# How does one install MarkLogic 8 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, marklogic

What are the steps to install MarkLogic 8 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Have you looked at the installation instructions from the official docs? http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_28962

Comment: Yes I saw that page but There are four options available,(windows,Red hat,Sun Solaris.,Mac) which one should I choose???

Comment: I think the following instructions contained in this archived exchange on the developer list will prove helpful, but I don't know if the startup scripts work out of the box for version 8: http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2014-February/014564.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, Yes I am able to install ML 8 . It's working perfectly.

Comment: Very good, glad to hear it. I'll submit a proper answer in case that link breaks, thanks for confirming that the instructions are valid for version 8.

Comment: FYI, MarkLogic is not officially supported on Ubuntu (although it works)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Alex Bleasdale/David Ennis, download the CentOS version; then:

Ubuntu and other Debian based distributions use DEB packages and CentOS or RedHat use RPM packages. To convert an RPM to DEB in a somewhat reliable way, one can use the 'alien' command. You install and use alien as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien --to-deb --verbose  [your downloaded version]
```

In order to install a local DEB package, you can use dpkg with the -i option.

```
sudo dpkg -i [your downloaded version new repacked as .deb]
```

At this point, MarkLogic should be installed. You can start and stop MarkLogic using the init script, it lacks the option 'status':

```
sudo /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
```

Answer (score 0):

Download RPM version for centos/redhat from marklogic official website. Need to install 'alien' to convert an RPM to DEB and install the DEB created.

sudo apt-get install alien

sudo alien --to-deb --verbose /home//Downloads/MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-5.4.x86_64.rpm

Install the deb:

sudo dpkg -i marklogic_8.0-6.4_amd64.deb

I have tested this on Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)