# Error Starting MarkLogic in Ubuntu

Tags: marklogic, ubuntu-16.04, marklogic-8

Hi im having error while starting MarkLogic on ubuntu.
I convert MarkLogic from this link [How does one install MarkLogic 8 on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947478/how-does-one-install-marklogic-8-on-ubuntu-14-04)

but while initializing

```
sudo /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start
```

i got an error

```
[....] Starting MarkLogic (via systemctl):MarkLogic.serviceJob for MarkLogic.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status MarkLogic.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

failed!

Help me! Thanks. Do i need to install dependecies?

Comment: What do "systemctl status MarkLogic.service" and "journalctl -xe" say?

Comment: @DaveCassel  I am also getting the same error..
On running "journalctl -ex" and systemctl status MarkLogic.service command I got -  "Starting MarkLogic: /opt/MarkLogic/bin/MarkLogic: error while loading shared libraries: libsasl2.so.3: cannot open shared o"

Comment: @DaveCassel please help!

Comment: I posted an answer on Feb 14th. You're probably missing a dependency and should be able to add that with a package manager.

Answer (score 0):

While MarkLogic is not supported on Ubuntu, it has been run there successfully in the past (* not an endorsement of doing so; don't do it in prod).

Running the commands specified in the error message should clarify what's going on. Based on Dixit's follow-up comment, yes, it appears this is the result of a missing dependency. You should be able to resolve that using `abt-get` or your package manager of choice.